# How can I get the numbers from tupple?

Tags: c, string, input, integer

I want to get an input from the user like (4,5).But I just want to get the integer values.(4 and 5) I wrote a code for this.But it did not work.How can I fix the problem.

```
int x, y;
int c;

c = getchar();
while (c != EOF) {
    while (c != '(' && c != EOF) {

        c = getchar();

    }
    while (c != ',' && c != EOF) {

        c = getchar();

    }
    x = c;

    while (c != ',' && c != EOF) {

        c = getchar();

    }
    while (c != ')' && c != EOF) {

        c = getchar();

    }
    y = c;
}
```

I get input(1,4). outputs is `x= 44` and `y= 45` ?

Comment: You should tag this as C rather than C++.

Comment: Which type is `c`? Converting a `char` to `int` uses its ascii code.

Comment: By the way, `I wrote a code for this.But it did not work.How can I fix the problem.` is a different way of saying "my code isn't working, please debug it for me", which falls under a very specific category for closing such questions.

Comment: You're looking for the comma twice.

Answer (score 1):

After you find the opening parenthesis, read characters while they are digits (see e.g. [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit)), and create your number.

When the character is not a digit, make sure it's a comma. If it is you read the next number the same as above. Finally make sure you got the closing parenthesis.

The above assumes that there are no whitespace between the parentheses and the numbers, or between the numbers or the comma. Those can be handled by looping and [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace).

---

As for converting digits to numbers, assuming your system is using [ASCII encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/) (which is standard on modern PC-like systems) then it's easy since you just subtract `'0'` from the character to get the digit (see the linked [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to help you understand why). Store the value in a variable, initialized to zero, and multiply by ten as needed.

---

Depending on the parser you're writing, you could do the handling and recognition of tuples in the parser instead of the lexer. That would make it more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

follow your code flow x value will be character comma.
    int c ,x ,y;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {

```
    while (c != '(' && c != EOF) {

        c = getchar();

    }

    c = getchar();
    x = c;

    while (c != ',' && c != EOF) {

        c = getchar();

    }

    /*x = c;

    while (c != ',' && c != EOF) {

        c = getchar();

    }
    */

    c = getchar();
    y = c;

    while (c != ')' && c != EOF) {

        c = getchar();

    }
    //y = c;

    printf("x = %c ,y = %c ",x,y);
}
```